# Finitely generated ideal question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring, $I \subset R$ is an ideal, and $I = \langle S \rangle$ is finitely generated where $S \subset R$. Show that if $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated ideals of $R$, then so are $I \cdot J$ and $I+J$.

Isn't this similar to saying that if two sets are finite, then their union or intersection is finite?

Comment: $I + J$ being finitely generated is related to the union of two finite sets being finite, but $IJ$ being finitely generated is related to the Cartesian product of two finite sets being finite.  Hope that is enough of a hint to get you going ...

Comment: Chase elements.